# How to run multiple feature files in sequence using Cucumber + protractor

Tags: protractor, cucumber, bdd, ui-automation, feature-file

I want to run feature files in a desired order or sequence, for example:

```
 tags:"`@ProtractorScenario` or @CucumberScenario"
```

But cucumber scenario is getting executed first. Can someone guide me on this?

> Note: Cucumber is executing scenario based on alphabetical order of feature file in folder

Also, in cases with more than 50+ feature files, what would be the best way to define sequencing of cucumber feature files?

Answer (score 3):

In order to have reliable tests, your tests should be independent and not rely on the order they are run in. The reason being that your test shouldn't depend on the system being in a certain state, as this will lead to flaky tests. Each of your tests should set up the expected state (and teardown!), so they can be run independently.

Answer (score 1):

Below is how protractor executes cucumber feature files:

1. Protractor finds out all feature files specified in `specs`, save the absolute file path into an array, let's call it `feature_list`.
2. Protractor starts a session (start a browser instance)
3. Protractor generates a Cucumber CLI as below, and execute the CLI to hand over the running control cucumber: 
   `./node_modules/bin/cucumber --require xxx --format xxx feature1,feature2,....featureN`

   feature1,feature2,....featureN calculated by `feature_list.join(',')`

From above, we can learn the only opportunity to change the order
is given an order-done `feature_list` to protractor `specs`.

> Note: every member of the `feature_list` should be absolute/relative
>   path of single feature file. `folder` and `wildcard` are not recommended to appear in the path.

You can get a solution code from my github: [spec.filter.js](https://github.com/yongcy/automation/blob/master/protractor/protractor-cucumber4-scaffold/supports/spec.filter.js), which implements:

1. filter feature file by cucumberOpts.tags
2. order filter result of above step 1 by priority

Guide to use `spec.filter.js`:

```
// protractor conf file
const specFilter = require('./spec.filter.js');

var config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'xxxxx',
    capabilities:'xxxx',

    framework: 'custom',
    frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
    ignoreUncaughtExceptions: true,

    specs: [
        './aa/**/*.feature',
        './bb/**/*.feature'
    ],

    cucumberOpts: {
        require: [
            'xxx'
        ],
        priorities: {
             // feature has tag @SPGC-21542 or @SPGC-21944 or @SPGC-21946
             // will has priority 1
            '1': ['@SPGC-21542 or @SPGC-21944', '@SPGC-21946'], 
             // feature has tag @SPGC-22055 will has priority 2, 
             // feature has heighest priority will put ahead at 
             // the `specs` list and get executed firstly.
            '2': ['@SPGC-22055']
        }
        tags: ""
    }

    ....
};

exports.config = specFilter(config);
```

Comment: How would you run multiple tags through protractor framework. I tried the below but fails npx cross-env ENV=qa TAGS=@Smoke,@Regression yarn test