# How can we set priority in cucumber scenarios by using tags

Tags: protractor

I am using protractor-cucumber framework, with protractor 5.2.2 and cucumber 3.2.1.
I have given tags in my config. file as given below

```
tags: '@valid or @invalid or @empty'
```

By default it will execute the scenario that we written first. But i need to set priorities for scenarios from different feature file, so that higher priority will run first.Thanks in advance

Comment: `protractor-cucumber-framework` doesn't support that.  You need to write additional code to do that.

Comment: You can look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49237818/how-to-run-multiple-feature-files-in-sequence-using-cucumber-protractor/49252906#49252906] as beginning.